# Overlay Flutter Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to overlay two `Container()` to obtain this effect:

[image: Image from Google]

but i don't understand how to do.

```
Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/images/' + image,
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position the widget inside `Stack` use [`Positoned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) or [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget.

```dart
child: SizedBox(
  height: 300 + 200, ///total height of inner children
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          ...
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          ....
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

You may also like [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)
.